# NSolve just spits out the input functions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I was trying to solve 3 equations with 3 variables with `NSolve`, however, `NSolve` didn't really do anything but spitting out the equations that I put in.

Frankly speaking, my equations look horrible, but according to the paper that I was referencing to, this set of equations should have valid solutions. Even if this is not the case, I would appreciate it with a "negative response" from Mathematica, instead of what I'm having right now.

So I'd appreciate if any geniuses could help me take a look at either the syntax or equations, and provide me with some suggestions. Let me say thank you beforehand!

(I made a lot of definitions, but those eventually boil down to numbers - as you could see by running the code and look at what `NSolve` spits out)

```
ξ = 79;
M = 4.2*10^-5;
Subscript[M, pl] = 1;
coord = {χ, φ};
metric = {{1, 0}, {0, 1/Exp[Sqrt[2/3]*χ/Subscript[M, pl]]}};
metric // MatrixForm;
inversemetric = Inverse[metric];
inversemetric // MatrixForm;

affine := affine = Simplify[Table[(1/2)*Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*
       (D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]] ] +
         D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]] ] - 
         D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]] ]), {s, 1, 2}],
    {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}] ]
listaffine := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
    0], {ToString[Γ[i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}] , {i,
    1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
  TableSpacing -> {2, 2}];
λ[φ_, Λ_] = Λ + 
   0.5/(16*π^2)^2*(Log[φ/(0.15*Subscript[M, pl])])^2;
U[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = λ[φ, \
Λ]/
     4 φ^4 Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] χ/Subscript[M, pl]] + 
   3/4*(Subscript[M, pl]*M)^2*
    Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] χ/
       Subscript[M, pl]] (Exp[Sqrt[2/3] χ/Subscript[M, pl]] - 
       1 - 1/Subscript[M, pl]^2 ξ*φ^2)^2;
Uderχ[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[U[χ, φ, Λ], χ];
Uderφ[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[U[χ, φ, Λ], φ];
D1[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[Uderχ[χ, φ, Λ], χ];
D2[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[Uderχ[χ, φ, Λ], φ] - 
   affine[[2, 2, 1]]*
    Uderφ[χ, φ, Λ];
D3[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[Uderφ[χ, φ, Λ], χ] - 
   affine[[2, 1, 2]]*
    Uderφ[χ, φ, Λ];
D4[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  D[Uderφ[χ, φ, Λ], \
φ] - 
   affine[[1, 2, 2]]*Uderχ[χ, φ, Λ];
Hess[χ_, φ_, Λ_] = 
  Simplify[D1[χ, φ, Λ]*
     D4[χ, φ, Λ] - 
    D2[χ, φ, Λ]*
     D3[χ, φ, Λ]];
NSolve[Uderχ[χ, φ, Λ] == 0  && 
  Uderφ[χ, φ, Λ] == 0 && 
  Hess[χ, φ, Λ] == 
   0 , {χ, φ, Λ}, Reals]
```

Comment: From help pages:"NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations. ",Try:`FindRoot`.

Comment: Your equations do seem rather challenging. Have you tried `FindRoot` with a good set of starting values? If this is a model for a physical process of some kind, you probably have an idea of the range of values that would make sense for your variables.

Comment: Try: `FindRoot[{Uder\[Chi][\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi], \[CapitalLambda]] == 0, 
  Uder\[CurlyPhi][\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi], \[CapitalLambda]] == 0, 
  Hess[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi], \[CapitalLambda]] == 0}, {{\[Chi], 
   8/10}, {\[CurlyPhi], 1/10}, {\[CapitalLambda], 1/100000}}]`

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! I will update if the problem is solved.